# Patching pathlib and testing the string during calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch, pathlib

I started using pathlib, and really like using it for the most part. The problem I'm having is testing it due to the nature of methods instead of functions.

```
def test_correct_dir_was_made(self):
    with patch('my.module.Path.mkdir') as mock_mkdir:
        check_dirs()
        mock_mkdir.assert_called_once()
```

In the `check_dirs` function, a path is generated dynamically and created if it doesn't exist. I can figure out how to make sure it was called arbitrarily, but my problem is I am not sure how to capture the self parameter passed into Path.mkdir to check that its path string was correct. With os.path this was easier, because mocking the mkdir function I could simply assert it was called with the correct string. Any ideas?

Comment: `mock_mkdir.assert_called_with("any path")`? is that what you needed?

Comment: This doesn't work, since the Path instance created in the `check_dirs` function calls the `.mkdir()` method and the `self` parameter which technically gets passed in is obscured from the mock object. If I try what you put, it says the expected call was `mkdir("any path")` and the actual call was `mkdir()`.

Comment: the `mkdir()` have no parameter defined, it is the `Path` class defines what directory to create. so the class `Path` is to be tested with directory.

Comment: Why not include your checkdir() listing? It makes a better example. Also, why does not checkdir take an arguement? Perhaps you can live with no mock at all and no hidden global state.

Answer (score 4):

I found a nifty solution. Trying to mock the whole Path class was proving very convoluted especially because I wanted the path class to do all the normal behavior except for modify the disk. What I found out was by enabling autospec, I could now assert the call including the 'hidden' self argument like so:

```
def test_correct_dir_was_made(self):
with patch('my.module.Path.mkdir', autospec=True) as mock_mkdir:
    check_dirs()
test_path = Path('path', 'to', 'test')
mock_mkdir.assert_called_once_with(test_path)
```

Now I can assert easily that the correct directory would have been made. There may be a way to mock the entire Path class with autospec and achieve a similar result, but it seems more sane to patch out the method I don't want and still be able to make assertions without having direct access to the instance that called the method.

Comment: are you sure about assert? coz am getting error as other params like `exist_ok` & `parents` are not passed

Comment: solved, below assert worked for me: `assert mock_mkdir.call_args == call(path, exist_ok=True, parents=True)`